# How can PHP transformer parameter return a single value from an array

Tags: php, algolia, transformer-model

```
 ->transformer(function (\craft\elements\Entry $entry) {
                    return [
                        'Area of Study' => $entry->areaOfStudy,
                    ];
```

Above is the function I'm using to return

This array

```
"Area of Study": {
    "label": "Public Administration/Social Services",
    "value": "Public Administration/Social Services",
    "selected": true
  },
```

What I'd like for it to return is this:

```
"Area of Study": "Public Administration/Social Services",
```

The array is sent to an Algolia indices via a dropdown in a form. The full return doesn't play nice in the indices.

Answer (score 0):

Can you test this :

```
->transformer(function (\craft\elements\Entry $entry) {
                return [
                    'Area of Study' => $entry->areaOfStudy['value'],
                ];
```

Comment: Thanks @Gary for the quick reply. I tried that and I got an error. I looked around a bit more and this worked for me: `'Area of Study' => $entry->areaOfStudy->serialize(),`